# Executing CQL through Shell Script?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I am trying to execute the CQL commands from shell script.
I am able to connect to the cqlsh (CQL version i'm using is 1.1.18) but unable to send the queries to cql.

Any ideas or suggestion how to proceed on this?
Do I need to connect to Cassandra and execute few commands (select/update ) with shell script ??

Answer (score 53):

```
cqlsh -e "select * from ks.table limit 1;" > ~/output
```

Comment: The `-e` flag was not available on cqlsh in version 1.1.18 (which is what the OP's question is about).

Comment: Sure, it wasn't available then. But it's incredibly useful to have the top Google results containing an up-to-date answer. 

The OP isn't going to accept any answer anyways.

Comment: @Aaron My Cqlsh version is 4.1.1. Earlier -e used to work, Not sure what is causing the error now. I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure about Cassandra 1.1.18, but you should be able to accomplish this with the `-f` flag of `cqlsh`.  Let's say have a file of CQL commands called "commands.cql".  I can invoke those commands against my local Cassandra instance like this:

```
$ cqlsh -f commands.cql -u myusername -p mypassword localhost
```

If I wanted to invoke that from within a Bash script, the script's code would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cqlsh -f commands.cql -u myusername -p mypassword localhost
```

Save that as an executable file, and run it like any other.

Answer (score 7):

> Need to connect to cassandra and execute few commands (select / update ) with shell script

You can execute your commands with shell script in next way:

```
echo "some QUERY; exit" | cqlsh CASSANDRA_HOST -u 'USER' -p 'PASS'
```

Answer (score 6):

The "exit" command in the last suggestion is a bit hacky.

I would propose using `xargs` with `cqlsh -e`.

`echo "some QUERY;" | xargs cqlsh CASSANDRA_HOST -u 'USER' -p 'PASS' -e`

I recently had to use this approach when working with docker, because `clqsh -f` was not an option (too complex to configure access to the file needed).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "some QUERY;" | xargs cqlsh CASSANDRA_HOST -u 'USER' -p 'PASS' -e
```

But what if you Cassandra instance is on a different server to where the shell script is being executed? (Specifically in StreamSets - wouldn't the above require Cassandra installed on the same server such that it has access to the cqlsh lib?)