# Cassandra drop keyspace, tables not working

Tags: cassandra

I am starting with cassandra and have had some problems. I create keyspaces and tables to go playing, if I delete them and then run a `describe keyspace` they keep appearing to me. Other times I delete them and it tells me they don't exist, but I can't create them either because it says it exists.

Is there a way to clear that "cache" or something similar?

I would also like to know if through cqlsh I can execute a .cql file that is on my computer.

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Comment: check `nodetool describecluster` that you don't have schema disagreement

Comment: nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Comment: Are you using AWS managed Cassandra?

Comment: Also for your cqlsh "execute a cql file" question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286253/executing-cql-through-shell-script/25287332#25287332

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the eventually consistent nature of Cassandra. If you are on a small test cluster and just playing around you could try doing CONSISTENCY ALL in cqlsh which will force the nodes to become consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You should always run delete or drop command manually with CONSISTENCY ALL so that it will reflect all the nodes and DCs. Also you need to wait for a moment to replicate into the cluster. Once replicated you will not get deleted data else you need to run a repair in the cluster.